# AWS Athena (Presto) - inner join syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, inner-join, amazon-athena, presto

What is wrong with this statement?

```
select e.*
FROM 
    edgar_revenue as e,
    INNER JOIN xbrl as x
    ON x."cik" = e."cik"
```

> line 4:5: mismatched input 'INNER'. Expecting: '(', 'LATERAL', 'UNNEST',

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it is the comma(,) after e

```
SELECT e.*
FROM 
edgar_revenue AS e
INNER JOIN xbrl AS x
ON x."cik" = e."cik"
```